# Can a battery output more amps than its rated Ah for a short time?

Tags: current

Say I need 150 DC amps to run a device for about 15 minutes.  Is a 12 volt 100Ah battery capable of delivering 150 amps for 15 minutes? I am disregarding peukart's law because I would use a lithium battery.

Comment: What does the data sheet say? It may be capable of supplying 15 amps for 6 or 7 hours but that doesn't necessarily translate to 150 amps for 40 mins or less.

Comment: There is no (well, very little) connection between a battery's Ah and A ratings. Look at the discharge current specs for the actual battery. There will be several, for continuous and short term discharge rates.

Comment: Amp-hours and amps are not the same unit. What you mean is a discharge rate of >1C.

Comment: How do you know about Peukert's Law but don't know the difference between amps and AH?

Answer (score 1):

Typical maximum discharge rate for a lithium ion battery is 2-20C, meaning that they can be discharged (in amps) at 2-20 times the capacity in Ahr.

Given the very high current you require, you will want to read the datasheets carefully when selecting a model of battery. Pay attention to have many charge cycles the device is rated for. At very high discharge rates it will have a reduced lifespan.

Comment: Helpful answer.  Thanks. Very interesting video on youtube of a guy who constructed a high C (3C's) out of Samsung 25R 18650 batteries to run a small microwave. His "product" resulted in a 30ah battery, He ran a 600 watt (50amp DC requirement). 
 Because of the high discharge rate of the batteries, he could run his  microwave for the short time he needed.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is a piece of cake, and you can do it with almost any battery chemistry (other than things like primary lithium).

As user1850479 answered, battery current is characterized in C units, where a 1 C current will (nominally) drain a battery in 1 hour. 150 amps from a 100 A-hr battery is only a 1.5 C current, and when applied for 15 minutes will draw about 37% of the battery capacity. This would actually be bad usage for lead-acids which are not deep-discharge models, as "regular" lead-acids start losing lifetime when discharged below about 90%. Of course, a pampered lead-acid will do thousands of shallow discharge cycles, and automobile batteries have a number of features which allow them to function adequately for longer than the above might suggest.